# Is it possible to have a Google Apps Script run a certain function after authorization / installation?

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm trying to figure out a good way to send a welcome email after someone authorizes my Google Apps Script Web App. Is there a native api to do this?

Answer (score 0):

The [onInstall](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/#available_types_of_triggers) function is only available for forms/sheets/docs.

However, you could just set a property such as "firstUse" with [PropertyService](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties/properties-service) and simply check if that property has been set. If not, do what you need to, then set the property.